# Detect and isolate veins in the palm?

Tags: image-processing, filters

[image: palm]

I am trying to figure out a way to find out the vein pattern in the hand.. Please could someone suggest ways to do the same.? I know first i would need to find the ROI in the image and perform further processing .. **Can gabor filter be used as one of the steps** ?

Thanks

Comment: See related question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694534/iphone-camera-application

Comment: my question is what is the programming languge for those code becuse i try to apply that on MATLAB but it dos'nt work and if there any equivelant code in MATLAB.
thanks
zainab

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ridge filtering seems like a possible processing. I have not tried to clean up the non-veins ridges; perhaps there would not be need for that step in more constrained acquisition conditions.

In Mathematica:

```
img = ColorConvert[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/5og5Z.jpg"], "Grayscale"];
r = RidgeFilter[ColorNegate@img, 3];
Binarize[ImageAdjust@r, .03] // Thinning
```

[image]

Comment: is there an implementation of ridge filtering in MATLAB?

Comment: There does not seem to be any implementation shipping with matlab. However, Google reveals user contributions to the matlab central exchange. According to the Mathematica documentation (http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RidgeFilter.html), ones needs to compute "the main principal curvature orthogonal to a ridge as given by the main negative eigenvalue of the Hessian matrix."

Comment: I find this concept a little hard to grasp !

Comment: One reference would be "Front-End Vision and Multi-Scale Image Analysis", by Bart M. Haar Romeny

Comment: will search and let u knw :)

Comment: Ridge filter as you suggested has been used in finger print detection etc but i am not able to find a code the description given in the mathematica website seems very trivial any other that i can find?

Comment: The book I referenced in my previous comment describes ridge filtering non-trivially. I would think there are other descriptions available online, but I have not searched for any.